# Customize /graphql endpoint to serve different schemas

Tags: graphql, hasura

In Hasura, is there a way to customise the `/graphql` endpoint so that for customer 1, it serves a schema at `/graphql/customer1` and serves another at `/graphql/customer2` for customer 2?

Currently, all my schemas are displayed in `/graphql` endpoint and it creates clutter and also makes the data visible to all when used with the graphiql interface.

Also, I have created my custom data-connector using dc-agents, if that information is of any use

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer. Although, this is not exactly what I wanted but perhaps better than what I wanted.

Hasura supports [Authorization roles](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/auth/authorization/roles-variables/) which can be used to configure permissions for any table against provided roles. So, in my case, the roles will be customer1/customer2 and permissions against a role can be assigned.

Hence, even with a single `/graphql` endpoint, I can customise the output for each customer